# Complicated array manipulation with dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I'm building a custom calendar-like thing for a client that won't accept out of the box behavior, and I'm having some trouble navigating how to piece together the array I need in order to display dates correctly.

Some background: this is a SharePoint-based solution where users input travel dates and locations on one list and a default location on another list.  The output needs to be a four week timespan that shows a user's location on any given day, whether it's one of these travel locations or a default (home office) location.

So I do a REST call to the travel list ([whereabouts]), one to the default locations list ([defaults]), and do some other stuff in code to build an array of dates going from today to today+28 ([allDates]).

I've tried a bunch of nested for loops and it's not really returning the right thing.  But I need to basically say: for each day in [allDates], is there an event in [whereabouts] with that date?  If so, then push the event title.  If not, then push the default location from [defaults].

I'm totally lost here, folks, any help is super appreciated.

**Edit**

In answer to Rajesh, [whereabouts] is an array of Events objects with the following properties:

- Date (UTC string)
- Event Length (string)
- Team Member (string)
- Title (string)

[allDates] is an array of date strings that go from today to today+28 days.

[defaults] is an array of objects with the following properties:

- Team Member (string)
- Location (string)

And an example of what I've got/am trying:

(After doing the REST calls and returning their data)

```
function initCal(){

    //Groups returned whereabouts data into arrays per team member name.
    var grouped = _(whereabouts).groupBy(function(o){
        return o.Team_x0020_Member.Title;
    });

    //Reduces the above to something a little more simple for me to work with.
    grouped = _.pairs(grouped)          

    //Full disclosure, this is going into a google charts data table.
    var tbl = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    //Building the allDates array and adding in day names.  
    for(var i=0;i<14;i++){
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";                
        var day = today.addDays(i);
        var d = weekday[day.getDay()];
        var n = day.toLocaleDateString();
        tbl.addColumn('string',n);
    }

    //I have to do some manipulation of the object google creates.  It looks kind of weird, but the output is that allDates array.
    var allDates = [];
    var colsArr = tbl.Kf;               
    for(var i=0;i<colsArr.length;i++){
        if(colsArr[i].label != ''){
            allDates.push(colsArr[i].label);
        }
    }

    //This is ultimately where the results will go.
    var rows = [];

    //Cycle through grouped, get the current team member, then go manipulate all these arrays using getEvents. 
    for(var i=0;i<grouped.length;i++){
        var thisTM = grouped[i][0];
        var whereabouts = grouped[i][1];
        rows.push([thisTM,getEvents(whereabouts,defaults,allDates)]);
    }

    //This is just where the data table goes.       
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('whereabouts'));
            table.draw(tbl, {width: '100%', height: '100%'});           

}

//Just needed something to get the day names.  Not important, left here because laziness.
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}


function getEvents(whereabouts,defaults,allDates){
    //Figure I'll put the finished results here and return this array.
    var events = [];

    //Empty array for formatted dates.
    var evDate = [];

   //Format the whereabouts date strings into locale date strings so I can do comparisons against the allDates date strings.
   for(var i=0;i<whereabouts.length;i++){
       var formatD = new Date(whereabouts[i].Date).toLocaleDateString();
          evDate.push(formatD);
   }

   for(var i=0;i<allDates.length;i++){
       for(var j=0;j<evDate.length;j++){
          if (evDate[j] === allDates[i]){
              events.push(whereabouts[j].Title);
          } else {
              events.push(defaults.Title);
          }
      } 
   }    
}
```

**Edit 2**
One more piece of context.  The thing that should be returned back to initCal should be an array that's exactly the same length as allDays but containing either an event title (if there is one) or the default location (if there is not an event on that day).

Does that make sense?  Thanks again for your help and your feedback.

Comment: Can you share what these variables look like?

Comment: Not my language of expertise, but if you want any help from anyone on here, it's a good idea to provide whatever code you have already tried.

Comment: Sure, all good feedback.  I've added a description of the arrays and the self-documented code I'm working with right now.

Comment: Instead of *toLocaleDateString* (which is entirely implementation dependent and produces different strings in different browsers) you should probably be using *toISOString*. It uses GMT though, so if you want a "local" date you can write your own 1 line format function to get whatever suits (maybe yyyy-MM-dd)..

Comment: @RobG, good note.  I think I was getting an error on IE in testing; just haven't gotten around to fixing it.  Any ideas about the primary question?

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer, but comments aren't big enough.

Presumably by "UTC string" you mean an ISO 8601 extended format date like "2016-03-29T10:43:23Z" or similar. Most browsers will correctly parse that but I'd recommend parsing it yourself to be sure (plenty of questions here on that).

For the comparison, if you just want to match dates (without time) then you *can* compare identically formatted strings, or you might just get the time value and compare that. The advantage of using the time value is that you can also use greater than and less than. Make sure to set the time to some common value first though, say noon (12:00:00) or midnight (00:00:00).

Either way, write a function to format the date the way you want.

There are plenty of formatters and parsers around if you don't want a library like moment.js (which kind of takes over everything), e.g. [*Date.format*](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/) and [*date-format*](https://github.com/barbir/js-date-format/blob/master/js/date-format.js), the second has a good little parser too. These will work with plain Date objects, whereas Moment.js creates its own wrapper around the Date.